# String to float and regex

Tags: python, regex, string, floating-point

I have a problem with regex and my string...

I need a solution in my regex code for take a float number of a string. I don't know why this code doesn't work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from re import sub



url = 'http://www.ebay.es/itm/PET-SHOP-BOYS-OFFICIAL-PROMO-BARCELONA-ELECTRIC-TOUR-BEER-CERVEZA-20cl-BOTTLE-/111116266655' #raw_input('Dime la url que deseas: ')
code = urllib2.urlopen(url).read();
soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
info = soup.find('span', id='v4-27').contents[0]
print info


info = sub("[\D]+,+[\D]", "", info)
i = float(info)
print i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\D` means **Non-digits**. You need to use `\d` instead. Look here for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

**Updated**

I see, that your approach is to replace all non-digits chars. To my mind, match needed information is more clear:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "15,00 EUR"
>>> price_string = re.search('(\d+,\d+)', s).group(1)
>>> price_string
'15,00'
>>> float(price_string.replace(',', '.'))
15.0
```